# gamma cross flashes secondary strip for 1-2 frames before fading

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

my videos have an intro clip that fades into my content strip. to fade, i use a gamma cross effect strip. overall the result is acceptable, but the first 1-5 frames of my gamma cross flash the content strip in near-full visibility before returning to the appropriate level of fade. then the strips fade as intended. any ideas why this might be happening?

i'm not sure what the policy is for this and i'm not intending to advertise here, but https://youtu.be/s43BSKDfq14?t=4s from :04 to :07 is an example of what i'm talking about. thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Got burned on this myself. It's sensitive to the order you select the clips. Selecting the second clip first gives you a backwards fade.